# Unable to import FuncAnimation in python for matplotlib animation

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to create an animation using matplotlib. This requires that I import  FuncAnimation. When I run

```
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
```

I get the following error:

```
CalledProcessError: Command '['convert', '--version']' died with <Signals.SIGABRT: 6>.
```

I am not sure what the issue is. I am using matplotlib 3.1.2. Is there any way to address this issue? Your feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you executing the import?

Comment: I am using Jupyter Notebook

Comment: Have you tried any other versions of matplotlib?

Comment: well, I currently have the latest version of matplolib. Do you mean that I should try an earlier version? I haven't tried an earlier version.

Comment: It's not unheard of for downgrading to resolve errors like this, it certainly could be worth trying. At the very least you can rule out version issues as the cause of the error